# Visual Studio 2017 Linux remote build - recompiling all cpp files on each build

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, arm, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community to develop application that is built on remote Linux machine (exactly Raspberry Pi 3). I have created a new project using Visual Studio's Raspberry Pi project template.

The problem is: even when I just change one line of code, the entire bunch of cpp files is rebuilding. My project consists 100+ source files and building time is reaching 10-20 minutes. It is really painful.

How can I change it, so building will only take place on changed file?

Comment: Does this [ https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/29 ] explain what you see?

Comment: @stanthomas  Yes, exactly

Comment: Options you might consider until this issue is fixed: 1) use a makefile; 2) install Debian on fast desktop and do your edit/build/test cycle there.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have changed building using MSBuild to CMake building, and now only changed files are compiled, build time has dropped from 20 minutes to 2 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was MSBuild bug - see [github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/29](http://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/29)

Changing MSBuild to CMake solved all problems.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a lot of includes in your header files. Try to move as many of them as possible to the cpp files.

Comment: Unfortunately I have moved all unnecessary references from header files to source files - nothing has changed

Comment: Yes, everything is included using forward declarations. Only in few cases, when I need objects (not pointers) as class fields I use classic including.

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers? It is possible that most of your headers are included in the precompiled header, which could cause massive recompilation.

Comment: No, I am not using any of precompiled headers. I use only codesynthesis library and files generated by codesynthesis's xsd.exe